# Updating column with sum(data) from other table

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, i'm drawing a blank here and in dire need of your help!

3 tables:

**matches** (id, goals_slot_1, goals_slot_2, won, draw)

**teams** (id, name, score_for, score_against, won, lost, draw, points)

**team-match (junction table)** (team_id, match_id)

So what i want to achieve, is to update the 'draw' column in the **teams** table SET to the 'sum(draw)' of the **matches** table of the according teams. 
The value of 'draw' in the matches table is '1' when it's a draw, '0' when not.

I just can't figure it out anymore. Stuck on it for days...
Can someone put me on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a correlated sub query to get the values from the other tables. Something like:

```
UPDATE `teams`
SET `draw`=(SELECT SUM(`draw`)
            FROM `matches`
            WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `match_id`
                           FROM `team-match`
                           WHERE `team_id`=`teams`.`id`))
```

Or even a single sub query with a join:

```
UPDATE `teams`
SET `draw`=(SELECT SUM(`draw`)
            FROM `matches`
                JOIN `team-match`
                    ON `team-match`.`match_id`=`matches`.`id`
            WHERE `team-match`.`team_id`=`teams`.`id`)
```

Both should do the work. I would assume the first is better for performance, but haven't tested and really they should be within a few milliseconds of each other. Other than this, you would need to use php to query the values and update the individual rows. Really though, the won/lost/draw columns could be calculated on the fly with similar performance and you wouldn't have to update the values every match.